# Swift - Search in string and sum the numbers

Tags: string, search, swift, numbers, sum

Hey guys I have string "69 - 13" How to detect "-" in the string and how to sum the numbers in the string 69+13=82 ?

Comment: No I am tryin to detect - and get the sum of the number 69 and 13 which is 82

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. Do you always have two numbers separated by a minus sign, or what is the general case?

Comment: yes I always have a minus sign which separates the two numbers and I want the sum of these numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various method to do that (`componentsSeparatedByString`, `NSScanner`, ...).
Here is one using only Swift library functions:

```
let str = "69 - 13"
// split string into components:
let comps = split(str, { $0 == "-" || $0 == " " }, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
// convert strings to numbers (use zero if the conversion fails):
let nums = map(comps) { $0.toInt() ?? 0 }
// compute the sum:
let sum = reduce(nums, 0) { $0 + $1 }
println(sum)
```

Comment: Link to Swift 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224936/swift-2-search-in-string-and-sum-the-numbers

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated implementation in Swift 4 that relies on higher order functions to perform the operation:

```
let string = "69+13"
let number = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
     .compactMap({ Int($0) })
     .reduce(0, +)
print(number) // 82
```

- The `components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)` removes all non-digit values and creates an array for each group of values (in this case 69 and 13)
- `Int($0)` converts your `string` value into an `Int`
- `compactMap` gets rid of any nil values, ensuring that only valid values are left
- `reduce` then sums up the values that remain in your array