# Swift 2 - Search in string and sum the numbers

Tags: string, search, numbers, sum, swift2

My old code was:

```
let comps = split(str, { $0 == "-" || $0 == " " }, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
```

after update of Swift 2 my XCode 7 fix it to:

```
let comps = split(str.characters, { $0 == "-" || $0 == " " }, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false).map { String($0) }
```

but now I have an error: `Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'`

How to fix it.

[Link to old answer on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508398/swift-search-in-string-and-sum-the-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of arguments for `split()` function messed up for some reason.  It should be:

```
let comps = split(str.characters, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false) {
    $0 == "-" || $0 == " "
}.map {
    String($0)
}
```