# Swift 2: Function counting occurrence in string not working

Tags: xcode, swift, count, swift-playground

I'm trying to learn `Swift 2` and **count frequency of G's and C's in the input string**.

I'm not getting any counts in my for-loop on the string.  Xcode suggests I use `let` instead of `var` since for `gc_count` since it is not updating (which should not be the case!).

I'm also getting this error at my `return` statement:

```
Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Float'
```

Tried [Swift 2 - Search in string and sum the numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224936/swift-2-search-in-string-and-sum-the-numbers)

```
func GC(input_seq: String) -> Float {
    let SEQ = input_seq.uppercaseString
    var gc_count = 0.0
    for nt in SEQ.characters {
        print(nt)
        if (nt == "G") {
            var gc_count = gc_count + 1
        }
        if (nt == "C") {
            var gc_count = gc_count + 1
        }
    }

    var length: Float = Float(SEQ.characters.count)

    return gc_count/length
}

let query_seq = "ATGGGGCTTTTGA"
GC(query_seq)
```

If I did this in Python, I would simply:

```
def GC(input_seq):
    SEQ = input_seq.upper()
    gc_count = 0.0
    for nt in SEQ:
        if (nt == "G") or (nt == "C"):
            gc_count += 1
    return gc_count/len(SEQ)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
if (nt == "G") {
    var gc_count = gc_count + 1
}
if (nt == "C") {
    var gc_count = gc_count + 1
}
```

with

```
if (nt == "G") {
    gc_count = gc_count + 1
}
if (nt == "C") {
    gc_count = gc_count + 1
}
```

If you write `var gc_count` inside the `if` body, you create a new local variable `gc_count`, which shadows the `gc_count` from the outter scope.

Also, use `let` for length, since you don't change it.

And since gc_count is `Double`, and your function returns `Float` and `length` is `Float`, you have to make some conversions somewhere. Or change some types.

With this considered and a few more improvements I got this:

```
func GC(input_seq: String) -> Float {
    let SEQ = input_seq.uppercaseString
    var gc_count = 0
    for nt in SEQ.characters {
        print(nt)
        if nt == "G" || nt == "C" {
            gc_count = gc_count + 1
        }
    }

    let length = Float(SEQ.characters.count)

    return Float(gc_count) / length
}
```

Comment: Incredible explanation.  Thank you so much, that really helps a lot!  It's weird going to Swift from Python for a few things.  Had no idea about the || for an or statement either.

Comment: @O.rka, you're welcome :) And welcome to the world of Swift) `||` and `&&` are common in C-like languages. Take a look at Apple's [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) basics. I think, it might save you some time in future :)

Comment: thanks a lot! yea, i'm taking this coursera class on introduction to swift programming

Comment: @O.rka, oh, I see. Then, I guess, it includes all the required basics :) Good luck!